# Why did my foreach loop stopped after 1st iteration?

Tags: php

Here is my code in the controller:

```
$retrievedMessages = $messages->getUserContactMessages($userId, $offset, Messages::MESSAGE_PER_PAGE);
$messagesRefId = array_column($retrievedMessages, 'ref_id');
foreach ($messagesRefId as $refId) {
    $messagesId = Messages::getTargetedContactMessageIds($refId); 
    foreach ($messagesId as $messageId) {
        $messagesContactModel = new MessagesContact();
        $messagesStatus = $messagesContactModel->getTargetedContactMessageStatus($messageId);
    }        
}
```

I printed some of the variables and this is what I get:

```
[17-Sep-2015 18:37:00 UTC] <pre>messagesRefIdArray
(
[0] => 6b7f5d06
[1] => 4fdd5045
[2] => 394824ab
[3] => dc56937a
[4] => 84048d4b
[5] => 3514d1e0
[6] => 7437f96c
[7] => fc7d9e2a
[8] => 180faa9b
[9] => b625a6cb
[10] => 98c07527
[11] => 1441b0b2
[12] => 835245c6
[13] => 89b7324f
[14] => e23be50b
[15] => 6f8096f2
[16] => d94de77f
[17] => 7f8660d8
[18] => 2df463cc
[19] => 6a98024f
)
</pre>

[17-Sep-2015 18:37:00 UTC] <pre>messagesIdArray
(
[0] => 760
[1] => 761
)
</pre>

[17-Sep-2015 18:37:00 UTC] <pre>messageStatusArray
(
[0] => 1
[1] => 0
)
</pre>
```

Here is my function in the model `Messages`:

```
public static function getTargetedContactMessageIds($refId)
{
    $obj = new self;
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM messages WHERE ref_id = :ref_id AND status != :message_deleted AND type = :message_type';
    $params = ['ref_id' => $refId, 'message_deleted' => self::STATUS_DELETED, 'message_type' => self::MESSAGE_TYPE_CONTACT];
    $result = $obj->getResultSet($sql, $params)->toArray();
    return array_column($result, 'id');
}
```

and here is my function in the model `MessagesContact`:

```
public static function getTargetedContactMessageStatus($id)
{
    $obj = new self;
    $sql = 'SELECT status FROM messages_contact WHERE message_id = :id';
    $params = ['id' => $id];
    $result = $obj->getResultSet($sql, $params)->toArray();
    return array_column($result, 'status');
}
```

As you can see there are many elements in the array but it only go through the first element and stopped. Am I missing anything?

Comment: do you have error reporting turned on?

Comment: Yes and it gives me no error.

Answer (score 1):

In each iteration you are overwriting the variables values, so in the end these variables keep the value of the last iteration.

if your goal is to get all `$messagesStatus` should do the following:

```
$messagesStatus[] = $messagesContactModel->getTargetedContactMessageStatus($messageId);
```

Comment: This points me in the right direction. Not actually solving it but thanks alot.